# How do I write multiple AND clause for unknown number of conditions

Tags: javascript

Wondering if this is possible to do in Javascript?

I have a set of conditions which is a set of filter criteria for a report

Just say these are the possible filter criteria: (somewhat pseudocode, don't worry about actual JSON structure),

```
'job' = 'developer'
'job' = 'tester'
'job' = 'manager'

'salary' = 'hourly'
'salary' = 'weekly'
'salary' = 'monthly'

'office' = 'downstairs'
'office' = 'upstairs'
'office' = 'remote'
```

Now I'm wanting to allow user to filter data, for example `Employee which job is either developer or tester who work hourly`

In this case I would have a javascript such as

```
if ('salary' == 'hourly' && ('job' == 'tester' || 'job' == 'developer')){
  return true;
}
```

but then if user want to add additional dimension to the filter, eg on top of that, filter for employees who work remotely , eg `office = 'remote'`

I would have to write something like

```
if ('salary' == 'hourly' && ('job' == 'tester' || 'job' == 'developer') && ('office' == 'remote')){ return true; }
```

My question is, is it possible to construct these AND conditions programaticaly, perhaps by iterating through an array of filter criteria, instead of manually spelling them  out like what I did above?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since JavaScript is a Turing-complete language, yes, it's possible.

Comment: For this case it is maybe possible to use the decorator pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and wrap every single condition around another condition. That way it is possible to chain the conditions unlimitedly.

Comment: search for "Matrix decision making model"

Comment: @Tom, Giving a vague answer is not going to help her. Why don't you provide some sample code showing the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/zLm5hmk6/)***

I would structure the arguments sent by key and value, such as this:

```
var terms = [];
terms.push({'job':'developer'});
terms.push({'job':'tester'});
terms.push({'job':'manager'});

terms.push({'salary':'hourly'});
terms.push({'salary':'weekly'});
terms.push({'salary':'monthly'});

terms.push({'office':'downstairs'});
terms.push({'office':'upstairs'});
terms.push({'office':'remote'});
```

It should be very easy to do this with json data. Next, I would prepare an object of values that held the sample data like this:

```
var values = {
  job: 'tester',
  salary: 'monthly',
  office: 'onsite'
};
```

Which should also be easy to manipulate from the json. Taking these, the terms could be iterated and placed into buckets. Each bucket will be or'd with itself. Each result of that bucket will be and'd with itself. And the end result will be the overall truthiness. In the demo, please look at the console for some of the checkmark logs.

```
function test(terms,values){
 var sets = {};
 for(var i in terms)
 {
  for(var term in terms[i]){
   sets[term] = sets[term] || [];
   sets[term].push(terms[i][term]);
  }
 }
 var truthValues = [];
 for(var key in sets){
   var truth = false;
   for(var val in sets[key]){
    console.log(values[key] +" == "+sets[key][val]);
    truth |= values[key] == sets[key][val];      
   }
   truthValues.push(truth);
 }
 console.log(truthValues);
 var endTruth = true;
 for(var bool in truthValues){
  endTruth &= truthValues[bool];       
 }
 return endTruth;
}

console.log(test(terms,values));
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using this approach to solve my problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but here is what I came up with:

```
var employees = [
    {name: 'Hannah', job: 'tester', salary: 'weekly', office: 'remote'},
    /* ... */
];

function getFilters(){
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "";
    // reset the filters
    var filters = {job: [], salary: [], office: []};
    // populate them with checkboxes values
    for(prop in filters){
        var els = document.getElementsByName(prop);
        for(var i=0; i<els.length; i++){
            if(els[i].checked) filters[prop].push(els[i].id);
        }
    }
    // apply the filters
    applyFilters(filters);
}

function applyFilters(filters){
    var count = employees.length;
    // for each employee
    for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
        var e = employees[i];
        var meetsRequirements = true;
        // see if each property is in the filters
        for(prop in e){
            if(prop != "name" && filters[prop].indexOf(e[prop])==-1) meetsRequirements = false;
        }
        // if it is the case, display it
        if(meetsRequirements) displayEmployee(e);
    }
}

function displayEmployee(e){
    document.getElementById("main").insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', "<div class='employee'><h4>" + e.name + "</h4><p>" + e.job + "</p><p>" + e.salary + "</p><p>" + e.office + "</p></div>" );
}
```

## JS Fiddle Demo


[image: Try it out and see if it fits your needs.]

Comment: Thanks! I had thought of similar solution before, however ended up with a different solution, still kinda similar to yours. Thanks. Really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on Salman's code, but simpler:

```
var matches = function (candidate, criteria) {
    return !Object.keys(criteria).some(function (k) {
        return criteria[k].indexOf(candidate[k]) < 0;
    });
};
```

Data used:

```
var criteria = {
    job: ['developer'],
    salary: ['weekly', 'monthly']
};

var john = {
    job: 'developer',
    salary: 'hourly',
    office: 'downstairs'
};

var jane = {
    job: 'developer',
    salary: 'monthly',
    office: 'remote'
};
```